# Attempting to create a GPS navigation program using Python and GPS/GLONASS U-Blox7

Tags: python, gps

[image: The theoretical path that will be followed]

Hey there, I'm new here. I'm a uni student working on an autonomous rover. We've managed to successfully control the rover using keyboard instructions and also used an Intel RealSense camera for obstacle detection. Our next goal is to create a program which takes waypoints (coordinates) as inputs and moves the rover on a path to reach the destination.

Before implementing this, I'm testing the code manually by walking around with my laptop hence instead of commands to move the wheels, there are commands like left, right, straight. The basic idea is that we have a GPS/GLONASS U-blox7 to constantly get coordinates and we want to use these coordinates to instruct the rover to turn left or right. Initially, we will determine the starting position and enter a destination. Based on this, the initial distance and initial bearing angle are calculated. Initial bearing angle can be thought of as the angle between North line and the line joining source and destination (i.e. ideal path). It's in out interest to move along this ideal path so when we start to move, we will update the CURRENT bearing angle and compare it to the INITIAL bearing angle. If current<inital, turn left and vice versa until we reach the destination.

Here is the code we have written so far:

```
import math
import time
from collections import namedtuple
import gps

coordinates = namedtuple("coordinates", ["latitude", "longitude"])
session = gps.gps(mode=gps.WATCH_ENABLE)


def get_bearing(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    bearing = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * (180 / math.pi)
    return (bearing + 360) % 360

try:
    waypoints = [
        coordinates(
            float(input("Enter waypoint 1 latitude: ")),
            float(input("Enter waypoint 1 longitude: ")),
        ),
        coordinates(
            float(input("Enter waypoint 2 latitude: ")),
            float(input("Enter waypoint 2 longitude: ")),
        ),
        coordinates(
            float(input("Enter waypoint 3 latitude: ")),
            float(input("Enter waypoint 3 longitude: ")),
        ),
    ]

    flag = 0
    current_waypoint_index = 0
    current_waypoint = waypoints[current_waypoint_index]

    while True:
        if not (session.valid):
        print('TPV')
        time.sleep(2)
            # not useful, probably not a TPV message
            continue

        if flag == 0:
            if gps.isfinite(session.fix.latitude) and gps.isfinite(session.fix.longitude):
                current_position = coordinates(session.fix.latitude, session.fix.longitude)

                x1 = current_position.latitude
                y1 = current_position.longitude
                x2 = current_waypoint.latitude
                y2 = current_waypoint.longitude

                initial_distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * 2 + (y2 - y1) * 2) * 100000
                initial_bearing = get_bearing(x1, y1, x2, y2)

                print("Initial Distance:", initial_distance)
                print("Initial Bearing:", initial_bearing)
                flag = 1


        if gps.isfinite(session.fix.latitude) and gps.isfinite(session.fix.longitude):
            current_position = coordinates(session.fix.latitude, session.fix.longitude)

            x1 = current_position.latitude
            y1 = current_position.longitude
            x2 = current_waypoint.latitude
            y2 = current_waypoint.longitude


            current_distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * 2 + (y2 - y1) * 2) * 100000
            current_bearing = get_bearing(x1, y1, x2, y2)

            print("Current Distance:", current_distance)
            print("Current Bearing:", current_bearing)
            

            if current_distance <= 0:
                print("Reached waypoint", current_waypoint_index + 1)
                current_waypoint_index += 1
                if current_waypoint_index < len(waypoints):
                    current_waypoint = waypoints[current_waypoint_index]
                    print("Navigating to waypoint", current_waypoint_index + 1)
                    x2 = current_waypoint.latitude
                    y2 = current_waypoint.longitud
                    flag = 0
            else:
                if not gps.isfinite(current_bearing):
                    print("Current bearing not available")
                else:
                    if current_bearing > initial_bearing:
                        print("Turn RIGHT")
                    elif current_bearing < initial_bearing:
                        print("Turn LEFT")
                    else:
                        print("Move STRAIGHT")
        else:
            print("Lat n/a Lon n/a")

        time.sleep(2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

session.close()
```

After some testing, these are the problems we've faced:

-The current distance value does not seem to be getting updated even upon reaching the destination
-There are some inconsistancies in the commands and the angles by which they are instructing us to turn left or right

Kindly provide any insight you may have about this. Currently using UBUNTU 18.04 and Python 3.6.9